# South schemamigration command depends on edited model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-south

I cannot modify or remove my `Parameter` model because it is somehow used by `schemamigration` command. Everything works fine with other models.

When I remove `Parameter.name` field and run `schemamigration my_app --auto` command I get:

```
FieldError: Unknown field(s) (name) specified for Parameter
```

When I remove the model and run `schemamigration my_app --auto` command I get:

```
ImportError: cannot import name Parameter
```

My models.py:

```
class Parameter(models.Model):
    algorithm = models.ForeignKey(Algorithm, related_name='parameters',
                                  null=True, blank=True, 
                                  verbose_name=_('Algorithm'))
    name = models.CharField(_('Option'), max_length=255, null=True)
    required = models.BooleanField(_('Required'), blank=True)
    default = models.CharField(_('Default'), max_length=255, 
                               null=True, blank=True)
    label = models.CharField(_('Label'), max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(_('Description'), null=True, blank=True)
    description_lt = models.TextField(_('Description LT'), null=True, blank=True)
```

How could I find out whats wrong? And how could I fix it?

Comment: Are you calling schemamigration on the specific app? or are you running it for all apps? (schmamigration app_name)? also are you running an initial schemamigration? or an auto?

Comment: @petkostas I run ``schemamigration my_app --auto``.

Comment: Is Parameter in the installed apps in your settings?

Comment: @petkostas Yes, ``Parameter`` is in ``my_app/models.py`` and ``my_app`` is added to settings.py ``INSTALLED_APPS`` dictionary.

Comment: Do you have name field registered in your admin.py as well (like in fieldsets)?

Comment: @petkostas I do not use Django-admin at all.

Comment: From the error above it seems you are registering both your model and your fields with either an admin instance, or a form instance django will complain if you remove either of them, search your files or 3rd party modules if you use your model in any of them.

Comment: @petkostas I do not register ``Parameter`` anywhere. I use this model only in ``forms.py`` and ``views.py``.

Comment: In your forms.py do you use the name field anywhere?

Comment: Yes, you are right! I used ``ModelForm`` for ``Parameter`` model and specified ``fields``. Removing it solved the problem. Write it as an answer and I will mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error above it seems you are registering both your model and your fields with either an admin instance, or a form instance django will complain if you remove either of them, search your files or 3rd party modules if you use your model in any of them.