# Unknown Column Error when Adding ForeignKey to existing model with Django South

Tags: python, django, django-south

I've been battling with this issue for several hours now and I'm at a loss. I'm adding a ForeignKey model reference to an existing model and then trying to run a migration with South:

```
class Existing(models.Model):
    existing_type = models.ForeignKey(ExistingType)
    new_model = models.ForeignKey(NewModel, default=None, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.existing_type.name
```

When I try and run manage.py schemamigation [app] --auto I get the following:

```
DatabaseError: (1054, "Unknown column 'core_existing.new_model_id' in 'field list'")
```

I've tried to manually create a migration file, but when I run it I get the same error message. Its almost as if some internal django process is preventing south from running as the models don't validate.

I'm aware I could manually update the database to fix this, but this is far from ideal given multiple devs working on this project as well handling this across multiple development environments.

Can anyone provide any insight?

I'm running:

django 1.5.5
south 0.8.4
mysql

EDIT:
Incidentally I cannot add ANY field type to this model, but I am able to create new models via south - if I comment out the additional field

Comment: Seems like [same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20890953/south-schemamigration-command-depends-on-edited-model) I got earlier. Do you use ``Django-admin`` or ``ModelForms``? I had to comment them in order to generate schemamigration.

Comment: Please post the _whole_ traceback. The most likely cause of your problem is some code issuing a query at the module level - which is something you don't want in Django anyway.

Comment: bruno, that is the only message I'm getting, there is no stacktrace or any further info other than "Database Error...." -- niekas that is a very annoying problem if that is the case, however commenting out and then uncommenting will be problematic for the same reasons mentioned above with manual database changes. I already have a manually created migration but am unable to run it

Comment: @elspiko run the command with the `--traceback` option.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers didn't know that option existed, thanks! It turns out I'm referencing that model in the __init__ of an modeladmin as niekas suggested which is causing it to break. Thanks for your help